# property-placeholder location from another property (Spring 3.1)

Tags: java, spring

I need to load an environment-specific property file, and I'd like to be able to both set it from the JVM (using -D) and to provide a default value in the main properties file or, failing that, somewhere else (like the applicationContext.xml)

I'm using the new hotness Spring 3.1 with its unified property management, but I can't find a lot of info on the property system.

**UPDATE:**

To clarify:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/myapp.properties,
                                        /WEB-INF/myapp-${deploy.env}.properties"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using Spring 3.1, JVM property will be put into placeholders and you can define default values using ":", for example:

```
${property1:defValue}
```

where **defValue** is default value, it can be overridden by JVM option **-Dproperty1=newValue**

Comment: You do not need Spring 3.1 for that Syntax, it is already included in Spring 3.0

Comment: Nope, doesn't work: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myapp-${deploy.env:win32}.properties]

Comment: @Aleksandr Dubinsky I have tested config <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/myapp-${deploy.env:win32}.properties"/>. It works fine, I have result: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/myapp-win32.properties] because really I do not have myapp-win32.properties file.

Comment: @e-zinc !@#_@!#)(#@#$)*(&~!#)*&@_)*$#@ SCREW JAVA !@#)_%@@#_@!#)*(&$ (P.S. I posted the exact applicationContext.xml and web.xml and I'm referencing Spring 3.1.0-RELEASE and using Tomcat 7.0.22 bundled with Netbeans)

Comment: @e-zinc and now it magically works... tada. I love computers.

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) API - it is pretty informative. Example [here](http://www.zparacha.com/how-to-read-properties-file-in-spring/).

EDIT

As the example points to outdated version of Spring the more modern approach is illustrated [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/ConfigurableEnvironment.html)

Comment: That's the old pre-3.1 way (and it wasn't very good in such scenarios). Was looking to learn about 3.1 advances.

Comment: @Aleksandr Dubinsky, The API is 3.1. The example is little out-dated but you can try the new one (see my edit in the answer), what "advances" you were looking for?